# VC++ 10.0 express gdi+ GdiPlusPen.h header

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gdi+

When i include GdiPlus.h,**Pen** class is undefined.

But GdiPlus.h includes GdiPlusPen.h

```
...
#include "GdiplusImageAttributes.h"
#include "GdiplusMatrix.h"
#include "GdiplusBrush.h"
#include "GdiplusPen.h" 
#include "GdiplusStringFormat.h"
#include "GdiplusPath.h"
...
```

When i include GdiPlusPen.h myself, it works. Can i use it safely?

**Question:** is this because of my VC++ being express install?

8 days left until activation prompt :( 
Anyone having same problem?

Windows XP sp-3, pentium-m centrino.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, #including GdiplusPen.h directly isn't correct.  The gdiplus classes live in a namespace named "Gdiplus".  Either use that namespace explicitly (like Gdiplus::Pen) or make it look like this in your .cpp file:

```
#include <gdiplus.h>
using namespace Gdiplus;
```

Comment: But now it is saying it is not a namespace name. I tried gdiplus GdipPlus Gdiplus and gdiPlus